# Having trouble with a dynamic fade in/fade out hover transition (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/XztsH/1/

The hover class seems to be pushed down a 20 pixel and I'm not quite sure why.

Maybe it's late and my brain is dead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift occured because the 'Close' text was occupying the line. Updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XztsH/3/

Comment: This absolute positioning method was my first instinct, too. But the line-height answer also works. Personal preference, I guess! I like both.

Comment: I'm acutally going to have to restructure this. Since I have two circle PNG's on top of eachother, the first one shows through and I need the parent to fade away as well.The way it's setup now, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Although you put the text far over the to left, it's still taking vertical space. The simplest fix would be to add this:

```
line-height: 0;
```

**See it [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/XztsH/4/).**

Comment: There are two rules. Specifically, add it to the first one (or really, just putting it to a new #close>a rule would work also).